# Upload from Android on Python AppEngine and read the file

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine

I want to send a csv file from Android to Python AppEngine. I'm using the Blobstore API and to send the file, I use `MultipartEntity`, `HttpPost` and `HttpGet`.

So, according to the Blobstore API, you must call the method `create_upload_url('/upload')` to generate the url to upload the file and you use this url as the *action* to upload the file. As you can read [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html)

What am I doing? I call a method that creates this url and return it to my android app. And with this url I upload the file.

The url generated is in this format:

> **myapp.appspot.com/_ah/upload/***a-lot-of-numbers-and-letters/*

Basically like this:

**Android Code**

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(mContext.getString("myapp.appspot.com/get_blobstore_url");

 HttpResponse urlResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

 result = EntityUtils.toString(urlResponse.getEntity());

 Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/dir/myfile.csv"); // Gets the Uri of the file in the sdcard
 File file = new File(new URI(fileUri.toString())); // Extracts the file from the Uri

 FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, "multipart/form-data");

 MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
 entity.addPart("file", fileBody);

 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(result);

 httpPost.setEntity(entity);

 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
 response.getStatusLine();
```

**AppEngine Code**

```
# Returns only the URL in which the file will be uploaded, so this URL may be used in client for upload the file
class GetBlobstoreUrl(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.info('here')
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        logging.info("url blob %s", upload_url)
        self.response.out.write(upload_url)

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        logging.info('inside upload handler')
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        return blob_info.key()

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/upload', UploadHandler), ('/get_blobstore_url', GetBlobstoreUrl)], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Question 1**

When I send the file to the url the AppEngine returned, this will automatically call the server method UploadHandler? Because the log message inside this method is not being showed, **and the file is being inserted**, and the response I get when uploading the file with the generated url is a 404 error, why that error if the file is being uploaded?

**Question 2**

After I upload the file, how can I parse the csv file in the server and insert all the data in the file to the datastore?

Thanks.

Comment: The android side is using `/generate_url` while the GAE side is providing `/get_blobstore_url`. Is that a typo in the code, or just the post?

Comment: just the post. They are the same url. I've typed it wrong. fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I send the file to the url the AppEngine returned, this will
>   automatically call the server method UploadHandler?

Correct.

> When I send the file to the url the AppEngine returned, this will
>   automatically call the server method UploadHandler?

Show us your server logs - what URL are you getting the 404 for? Do you get any log messages from the upload handler?

> After I upload the file, how can I parse the csv file in the server
>   and insert all the data in the file to the datastore?

Use the [BlobReader API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass.html), and pass the opened file to the python `csv` module.