# Upload file to GAE blobstore (Python) from android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, python-2.7, apache-httpclient-4.x

Below is the code i have tried using. Copied it from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467745/upload-from-android-on-python-appengine-and-read-the-file) :

```
public void sendToServer() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.prescuem.appspot.com/report");

    HttpResponse urlResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    String result = EntityUtils.toString(urlResponse.getEntity());
```

i have tried:

```
 Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("file:///" + filename); // Gets the Uri of the file in the sdcard

    File file = new File(new URI(fileUri.toString())); // Extracts the file from the Uri
```

and

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("file://" + filename); // Gets the Uri of the file in the sdcard

        File file = new File(new URI(fileUri.toString())); // Extracts the file from the Uri
```

and

```
File file = new File( context.getFilesDir(), filename );
```

none of this way of adding the file has worked.

```
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, "multipart/form-data");

    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    entity.addPart("file", fileBody);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(result);
    show(result);

    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    response.getStatusLine();
    show(response.getStatusLine().toString());

}
```

filename is like :"/storage/sdcard1/send.png"

Server side code is like:

```
class GetBlobstoreUrl(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.info('here')
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        logging.info("url blob %s", upload_url)
        self.response.out.write(upload_url)


class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        self.response.write('uploaded')
```

when, i upload from my android device, i get interner server error and when i check my log on GAE dashboard, it is like this:

```
2014-08-16 13:16:51.658 /upload 500 175ms 1kb Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4) module=default version=1
0.1.0.30 - - [16/Aug/2014:13:16:51 -0700] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 1832 - "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" "www.prescuem.appspot.com" ms=175 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000205 app_engine_release=1.9.9 trace_id=7d164e50e0f57814373999d3f4c3669e instance=00c61b117cd4ccecda5feef9443470c8a00c9f43
E 2014-08-16 13:16:51.656
list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~prescuem/1.378016087775419183/main.py", line 124, in post
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

how do i fix this pls.

Answer (score 0):

Check `filename`.  If it starts with a leading slash, then your uri has too many slashes:

```
"file:///" + filename # filename = "/storage/sdcard1/send.png"
```

becomes:

```
"file:////storage/sdcard1/send.png"
```

log the filename before you send it, and make sure it exists.

Comment: even when i use "file://" or when i use "File file = new File( context.getFilesDir(), filename );", it does not work and the file actually exist on my android devices (i used intent to select a file and get the path)